# Change default select statuses?

Tags: channel-entries, status

Is there any way to change the default statuses displayed by the channel:entries tag to "not closed"?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `status="not closed"` to your `channel:entries` tags. If you do not specify a  `status` parameter, it will always assume `open`.

Comment: I'm looking to change the global {exp:channel:entries} default, not each individual instance.

Comment: Not possible without hacking core.